# How to stop CSS flex column from filling width in three-columns row?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a flex row that should contain three columns. Three columns per row looks good, but when having two columns in one row, second column is pushed to the right side of the row, as can be seen in the image below.

[image]

From the image, red lines shows how I would like all columns to be placed.

Row has this CSS:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
flex-flow: row wrap;
```

While columns has this CSS:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

In addition, using Bootstrap 4, row uses *row* class, columns uses *col* classes

How can I keep two columns in a row at the same positions as it would be with three columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this with flexbox you can try using `justify-content: flex-start;`. To get 3 columns per row, apply `flex-basis: ~30%;` to the flex items. Something like this:

```
 .container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.block {
  background-color: grey;
  flex-basis: 30%;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yrad5mqh/)

Hope it helps!